# How to disable <option> according to <option selected>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have a list of users and each has a role.

The user who is selected as "Líder" can not have more than one role, only "Líder".

If the user selects another option (daughters) the option "Líder" should be disabled. Users who are not "Líder" can have more than one role.

Here is a simulation of the problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/33q72pto/)

HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="funcao" multiple data-max-options="1">
  <option value="lider">Líder</option>
  <option value="conhecimento">Para Conhecimentor</option>
  <option value="participante">Participante</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select class="selectpicker" id="funcao" multiple data-max-options="1">
  <option value="lider">Líder</option>
  <option value="conhecimento">Para Conhecimentor</option>
  <option value="participante">Participante</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select class="selectpicker" id="funcao" multiple data-max-options="1">
  <option value="lider">Líder</option>
  <option value="conhecimento">Para Conhecimentor</option>
  <option value="participante">Participante</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select class="selectpicker" id="funcao" multiple data-max-options="1">
  <option value="lider">Líder</option>
  <option value="conhecimento">Para Conhecimentor</option>
  <option value="participante">Participante</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var sel = $(this); 
    var data = sel.data('prev'); 
    var val = sel.val();
    var prev; 
    if(data){ prev = data.val; }
    sel.data('prev', {val: val}); 
    sel.nextAll().each(function(){
        if(prev){
            $(this).find("[value='" + prev+ "']").prop("disabled",false);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
        $(this).find("[value='" + val + "']").prop("disabled",true);
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/33q72pto/

Comment: I almost got what I wanted, but the user who was selected as the "Líder" has the option disabled ... and at the time of sending the form it presents an error.
The error happens because option of select (parent) is also disabled and in sending the form, this option is empty ...
https://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/9e2ovnth/

Comment: add `multiple data-max-options="1"` attribute in select tag like `<select class="selectpicker" id="funcao" multiple data-max-options="1">`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the effect obtained with the code below - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spprmr23/1/)

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var sel = $(this);
    disableThis(sel);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});

function disableThis(sel) {
    var temSelecionado = false;

    $("option[value='1']").each(function() {
        if (this.selected) {
            temSelecionado = true;

            $(this).parent().each(function() {
                $(this.options).each(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() != "1") {
                        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                })
            });
        }
        else {
                $(this).parent().each(function() {
                $(this.options).each(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() != "1") {
                        $(this).prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: That's almost it, @Arkej. However if some select is selected as "Leader", this option must be disabled in the other selects ...

Comment: I changed a logic ... and found a new problem:

How do I, when I deselect a specific select option, return it to the "initial state"?

Here is a simulation of my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/o1xs3m8x/